# open different sheets of excel and write to it using c++

Tags: c++

I have an input file "inputfile.txt" from where I am reading input.

inputfile.txt is :-

```
|I|line|number|1

|P|line|number|2

|I|line|number|3

|P|line|number|4

|I|line|number|5

|P|line|number|6
```

Now I am processing this file according to the condition that if second char is I then it will write into "Iout.xls" and if it is 'P' then write to "Pout.xls"

Iout.xls :-

```
|I|line|number|1

|I|line|number|3

|I|line|number|5
```

Pout.xls:-

```
|P|line|number|2

|P|line|number|4

|P|line|number|6
```

both are excel files seperated by pipe.

here is my code what I am doing:-

```
#include<iostream>
#include<fstream>
#include<string>
#include<vector>
using namespace std;
int main() {
 ifstream in;
 ofstream Iout,Pout;
 string str;
 string::iterator it;
 in.open("inputfile.txt");
 Iout.open("Iout.xls",fstream::app);
 Pout.open("Pout.xls",fstream::app);
 if(in.is_open()){
  while(in.good()) {
   getline(in,str);
   it=str.begin()+1;
   if(*(it)=='I')
     Iout<<str<<endl;
   if(*(it)=='P')
     Pout<<str<<endl;
  }
 }
 else cout<<"can't open file";
 Iout.close();
 Pout.close();
 in.close();
 return 0;
}
```

I have two queries:-

1.I am inserting values as a text into excel (for e.g., "|P|line|number|2" is inserted as a text into Pout.xls) and there I am doing text to column manually, Is there any way to automate this using c++.

i.e., |P|line|number|2 will be inserted as:-
  space in first column,P in second column,line in 3rd column,number in 4th column and 2 in 5th column.

my second query:-
I am writing two different files Iout.xls and Pout.xls and then after converting from text to column in both the files,I copy both files into a single file FinalOut.xls with two different sheets Iout and Pout containing the data of Iout.xls and Pout.xls.
How can I open different sheets of an excel file with c++ and write corresponind data directly to the sheets.

i.e., sheet1 will be Iout 
and sheet2 will bePout.

I am using devc++ for my code.

Thank You

Comment: Do you need to do this in C++? There are command line tools to do this in a one-liner.

Comment: @PeterWood yes,I need to do this in C++,if this can be done with commands then perhaps I can execute command line commands using system() function of c++.

Comment: @PeterWood No now its not necessary this to be done in c++, if this could be done using batch file then its also good. will you guide me in this direction.

Answer (score 1):

Excel is capable of importing HTML-based files - checkout the official documentation at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/Aa155477%28office.10%29.aspx

Since HTML is "text-based" you should be able to write is rather easily...

Another option is to use CSV (also text-based) which Excel does understand BUT there is no support in CSV for different sheets.

XLS is a binary file format defined by Microsoft which is rather complex... one option is a commercial library like [LibXL](http://www.libxl.com/) - it can read and write the "genuine Excel format (XLS etc.)" including support for different sheets etc.